# How to get large volume of CouchDb data through Java API?

Tags: couchdb, ektorp

I am using Ektorp API to get from CouchDB, but to get 5 millions records it tooks 8 min(Apporx) on standalone machine. IS there any way to getch record faster.

I have created view on top of couchDB database and view result contains 5m records.

List results = db.queryView(query, Map.class);

where db is instance of CouchDbConnector class from Ektorp API.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No, but currently we are using Talent tool to fetch data in batch(10000) but it also takes the same amount of time.

Comment: that's a pity (